# How to get the auto generated name for a specflow scenario-outline title in code for reporting purpose

Tags: c#, cucumber, bdd, specflow

I have a Scenario outline like below

```
Feature: Test Reporting
    Scenario Outline:  Verify pushing data to Event hub using API concept
       Given User Insert Geo Infomation to LoadCollection '<ScenarioId>'

Examples:
| ScenarioId | 
| Scenario_00 | 
| Scenario_01 |
| Scenario_02 |
```

In testExplorer(I am using MSTest) i am seeing the scenarios like below

```
TestReportingFeature
-->VerifyPushingDataToEventHubUsingAPIConcept_Scenario_00
-->VerifyPushingDataToEventHubUsingAPIConcept_Scenario_01
-->VerifyPushingDataToEventHubUsingAPIConcept_Scenario_02
```

I Coded like below to get the test name

```
var title = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title;
```

above code returning like **VerifyPushingDataToEventHubUsingAPIConcept** the **Scenario_00** are not getting appended.

I am expecting **VerifyPushingDataToEventHubUsingAPIConcept_Scenario_00** to be returned, Please help me how to get it.

Comment: Append the scenario id to the description -- Verify pushing data to Event hub using API concept '<ScenarioId>'

Comment: @Grasshopper, when I update the scenario-outline like **Verify pushing data to Event hub using API concept<ScenarioId >** in feature file  then the same line is being read through code, it's not getting updated like **Verify pushing data to Event hub using API concept_Scenario_0**.. I believe there should be some way to achieve which I am not sure of it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: U could add thr underscore to the description.

Comment: I just looked into the featurefile.cs file and noticed that below line of code is setting the value for variant. Is there way we can get this value during run time.

  **[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestPropertyAttribute("VariantName", "1")]**

Comment: @Grasshopper, i tried with underscore and other different combination, it's not working.